# Is it possible to set custom header for https-proxy-agent when using ws?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am asking this question because of the third party npm package `faye-websocket-node` supports this feature:

```
var WebSocket = require('faye-websocket');
var ws = new WebSocket.Client('ws://www.example.com/', [], {
  proxy: {
    origin:  'http://username:password@proxy.example.com',
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'node'},
    tls:     {cert: fs.readFileSync('client.crt')}
  }
});
```

I also like to accomplish similar result with the more 'native' and up-to-date `https-proxy-agent` and `ws`, but they don't seem to have any documentation on how to accomplish this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = url.parse('http://proxy.com');
options.headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'node'
}
var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(options);
```